# Cumulative sum that resets based on the year

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, cumulative-sum

I have a pandas df:

```
pd.DataFrame({'team': ['ARI','ARI','ARI','BAL','BAL','BAL','BUF','BUF','BUF'],
          'year': [2019, 2019, 2020, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2019, 2019, 2020],
          'week': [16,17,1,16,17,1,16,17,1],
          'hits': [1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 5, 3, 3, 2]})
```

I want to overwrite the "hits" column to a cumulative sum, but the cumsum must reset every "year".
Expected output:

```
pd.DataFrame({'team': ['ARI','ARI','ARI','BAL','BAL','BAL','BUF','BUF','BUF'],
          'year': [2019, 2019, 2020, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2019, 2019, 2020],
          'week': [16,17,1,16,17,1,16,17,1],
          'cumsum_hits': [1,4,2,2,4,5,3,6,2]})
```

Comment: `df.groupby(['team','year'])['hits'].cumsum()`

Comment: The week column needs to be included like in my expected output.

Comment: Assign that to a new column in your dataframe: `df['cumsum_hits'] = ...`?